# ProxyPassMatch with regex

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

The url i'd like to proxy pass looks something like this, could you please help me figure out the correct regex. I'm a apache newbie.

`https://example.com/v1/documents?uri=root/support/bugtracking/attachments/29099/support-log.txt`

I'd like  `root/support/bugtracking/attachments/29099/support-log.txt` to be passed to `https://other-server/download.xqy?file=root/support/bugtracking/attachments/29099/support-log.txt`

Currently i have the below configuration which does not seem to be working:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/key.pem
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/ca.cert.pem

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9050/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9050/
    ProxyPassMatch ^/v1/documents?uri=(root/support/bugtracking/*)$ https://other-server.com/download.xqy?file=$1
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match against the query string with ProxyPassMatch. You'll have to use mod_rewrite to do it.

```
# XXX: This creates a "worker" for this backend when
# not using ProxyPass.
<Proxy  https://other-server.com/>
# Actual thing being set is redundant
  ProxySet keepalive=On 
</Proxy>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} uri=(root/support/bugtracking/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/v1/documents https://other-server.com/download.xqy?file=%1 [P]
```

Comment: May not work verbatim, that is the general idea though

Comment: I have PT flag instead of P. Force of habit!

Comment: Thank you very much.  Works now.