# ProxyPassMatch for query string not working apache

Tags: regex, apache, apache-config

I proxy the main page (homepage) to another site with a different design using `ProxyPassMatch` and it works for this case.

I'm trying to match if:

```
example.com/?q=fsds
```

is present in the query string and if ignores it, but it's not working in any way. Any idea?

Configuration:

```
ServerName https://a24dev.ga
DocumentRoot /home/bitrix/www

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

# ProxyPreserveHost on
# ProxyPassMatch ^/?q= !

ProxyPassMatch ^/$ "https://product-qa.z.apteka24.ua"
```

Comment: Can you please show (the relevant part of) your apache configuration.

Comment: Of course.

ServerName https://apteka24.ua
        DocumentRoot /home/bitrix/www

       SSLProxyEngine on
       SSLProxyVerify none
       SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
#     ProxyPreserveHost on

#ProxyPassMatch ^/?q= !
ProxyPassMatch ^/$ "https://product-qa.z.apteka24.ua"

Answer (score 1):

You can't match query string parameters using `ProxyPassMatch`, see [ProxyPassMatch with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112396/proxypassmatch-with-regex)

You should, on the other hand, be able to put that directive inside a LocationMatch directive, and use a condition on the query string:

```
<LocationMatch "^/$">
    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^q=/">
        ProxyPassMatch ^/$ !
    </If>
    <Else>
        ProxyPassMatch ^/$ "https://product-qa.z.apteka24.ua"
    </Else>
</LocationMatch>
```

Note that the first argument of `ProxyPassMatch` doesn't matter when used in a `LocationMatch` directive as it will use the one that already matched.

UPDATE: It seems like you can't use `ProxyPassMatch` in `If` sections, very annoying, so you have to use RewriteRules with the `P` flag instead, if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^q=$
RewriteRule ^$ "https://product-qa.z.apteka24.ua" [P]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
When I tried to run this configuration, I got an error
`ProxyPassMatch cannot occur within <If> section`
I`ve indicated ProxyPassMatch on the same line as <IF but got the following error
`ProxyPassMatch cannot occur within <Else> section`
I`ve indicated ProxyPassMatch on the same line as <Else but got the same error
`<Else> directive missing closing '>' `
My final config here
`<LocationMatch "^/$">
    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^q=/"> ProxyPassMatch ^/$ !
    </If>
    <Else> ProxyPassMatch ^/$ "https://product-qa.z.apteka24.ua"
    </Else>
</LocationMatch>`

Comment: This is not a configuration issue, more like an Apache "bug" that prevents you from using `ProxyPassMatch` in `If` sections, annoying... https://serverfault.com/questions/605867/apache-2-4-proxy-for-external-redirect-for-internal

Comment: I updated the answer with a RewriteRule alternative